# Cant insert values via php into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm new to PHP/SQL and tried a tutorial.
I created a database with an user who has read and write permissions. Also a table named "employees" with columns: username, password, email, token

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Account erstellen</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
      require("mysql.php");
      $stmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE USERNAME = :user"); //Username überprüfen
      $stmt->bindParam(":user", $_POST["username"]);
      $stmt->execute();
      $count = $stmt->rowCount();
      if($count == 0){
        //Username ist frei
        $stmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE EMAIL = :email"); //Username überprüfen
        $stmt->bindParam(":email", $_POST["email"]);
        $stmt->execute();
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();
        if($count == 0){
          if($_POST["pw"] == $_POST["pw2"]){
            //User anlegen
            $stmt = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO employees (USERNAME, PASSWORD, EMAIL, TOKEN) VALUES (:user, :pw, :email, null)");
            $stmt->bindParam(":user", $_POST["username"]);
            $hash = password_hash($_POST["pw"], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
            $stmt->bindParam(":pw", $hash);
            $stmt->bindParam(":email", $_POST["email"]);
            $stmt->execute();
            echo "Account created successfully";
          } else {
            echo "Passwords doesn't match";
          }
        } else {
          echo "E-Mail is already used";
        }
      } else {
        echo "Username not available";
      }
    }
     ?>
    <h1>Account erstellen</h1>
    <form action="register.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required><br>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" required><br>
      <input type="password" name="pw" placeholder="Passwort" required><br>
      <input type="password" name="pw2" placeholder="Passwort wiederholen" required><br>
      <button type="submit" name="submit">Erstellen</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <a href="index.php">Do you have already a account?</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

After entering username, mail and 2x password into my form and click on "create" I get the message "Account created successfully" but the values aren't in my database.

I tried to debug it with F12(Firefox)the parameters get passed.......

Comment: Check the server's error logs.

Comment: After `$stmt->execute();` use https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php that will tell you if it inserted a row or not. The `execute` call just means to was sent.

Comment: The value returned by `$stmt->execute()` should not be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount

RowCount does not return the count for select queries under some conditions. You could get the results of the query with a `if ($stmt->fetchColumn() !== false)`.

Also, there's no error handling for the $stmt->execute (unless you have the exception turned on: `$mysql->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`), so it will present "Account created successfully" even if that statement failed. Try `if ($stmt->execute()) { good } else { bad }` That's also a good place for the `->rowCount()`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help!

My mistake was a dumb one.. I didn't accepted "null" values for "Token" so the insert failed everytime. Thanks for the tipps I'll do an error handling :P